# SQLite Add Space After Commands

Tags: sqlite, command, newline, space

Is there a way to automate adding a new line or two after each SQLite command I run in a prompt? I don't like having walls of unorganized commands and I have problems differentiating the actual commands with the end of each output.
Can they be separately colored? I'm using a Windows Batch file, so I doubt it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're executing your commands, but you should be able to add some 'line breaks' by adding `SELECT '';` in between SQL commands. This doesn't really work if you're outputting column headers though!

In Batch, if you're returning to the command line after each command, then use `echo.` to print a blank line.